# How do I access properties of objects inside another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an api endpoint form where I am getting data like below. How i will access the values title, short_title etc.

```
 blog: {
    paginations: true,
    isLoading: false,
    particularBlog: [],
    count: 13,
    next: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blog/all-blog/?page=2',
    previous: null,
    results: [
      {
        id: 47,
        user: 1,
        title: 'adasd',
        short_title: 'asd',
        publish: '2019-09-16',
        slug: 'adasd',
        comments_count: 0,
        likes_count: 0
      },
      {
        id: 46,
        user: 1,
        title: 'adasda',
        short_title: 'asdas',
        publish: '2019-09-16',
        slug: 'adasda',
        comments_count: 0,
        likes_count: 0
      }
    ]
  },
```

what i have done is

```
<div>{
       this.props.blog && Object.keys(this.props.blog).map((key) => {
       return <p>{this.props.blog.results[key]}</p>
     })
}</div>
```

but it is giving error stating paginations' of undefined. Can someone please pointout what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: `this.props.blog.results.map(result => <p>{result.short_title}</p>);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is what is happening

`Object.keys(this.props.blog).map((key) => {` is getting the `keys` of `this.props.blog` and `this.props.blog.results[key]` is trying to access the properties of `results` with the keys of `blog`.

What you should do is have another `.map` with `Object.keys` of `this.props.blog.results`

OR

What I think you are trying to do is list all properties on the `this.props.blog.results` array, so here is what you can do

```
this.props.blog && this.props.blog.results && this.props.blog.results.map(result=> <p>{result.short_title}</p>
```

You do `.map` on the `results` array and display `short_title`.

Answer (score 0):

```
blog.results.map(el => (<div>{el.short_title}</div>))
```